# the norm a functional that maps a convergent sequence to its limit

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Given the linear space $\vec{E}$ of real convergent sequences, dotated with the norm 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\| \cdot \| : \vec{E}&\to \mathbb{R} \\
x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} &\mapsto \|x\|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |x_n|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and the function
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
l : \vec{E}&\to \mathbb{R} \\
x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} &\mapsto l(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
prove that $l$ is a continuous linear function and calculate its norm on $\mathcal{L}(\vec{E},\mathbb{R})$.
I think that the norm is 1 but i would appreciate if someone could help me with it.

PS: this is not homework, i just saw this and needed to know the answer hahah

Comment: Where you wrote "dotated," I would guess that you are thinking of Spanish "dotado," so the English word you want is "endowed."

Comment: thanks! i didn't know which word to use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm is indeed $1$. First, you want to show $|l(x)|\le\|x\|$ for all $x\in\vec E$ (which implies $\|l\|\le1$). That is, you want to show that if $x_n\to x$,

$$|x|\le\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|x_n|.$$

To show $\|l\|\ge1$, it suffices to find a sequence $(x_n)$ such the above inequality is an equality. Are you able to find such a sequence?